# Why I am getting too much "Flood Wait Error"?

Tags: telegram, telethon

I have a very simple application for sending bulk messages.
It sends a single message to 20 groups.
The delay that I declare between send messages is "8".
It means about 7~8 send message request per minute.
The documentation says "telegram api has a limit of 20 request per minute".
It means I am using **less than half** of the limit.
But still, I am getting lots of flood wait errors.
And those wait errors has like **84.000second** wait limit.

I am facing 2 errors while getting floodwait error.

1-

```
Security error while unpacking a recevied message: Server replied with a wrong session ID
```

2-

```
Floodwaiterror invoked while sending a message; forcing 70792 second wait interval for ....
```

I really don't know why this is happening.

- The number I am trying to send message is brand new. Clear. Unbanned. Unspammed.
- As I said wait interval between 2 messages is 8 seconds, means less than the limits for a minute.
- Sessions are correct because it sends couple message but after couple it gets instantly tons of floodwaiterrors from 0 to 70k.

Could you help me to understand what is causing that please?

Comment: You must share code (functions that you are using) then we can help you better

Comment: @Purya my project is too big to share but in short imagine a code block like telethon connect, telethon send and time.wait, three lines in a loop that looping channel list. thats all actually

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and solution is to pass the entity object instead of string name of receiver party.

was:

```
results = await client.send_message("mybot", message="hello")
```

now:

```
with TelegramClientSync(StringSession(session_id), api_id, api_hash) as client:
  bot_entity = client.get_input_entity(peer="mybot")
results = await client.send_message(entity=bot_entity, message=message)
```